# Prevent delete if account has child opportunities?

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to write a trigger in which if an account that has related Opportunity and the user tries to delete that account it throws you an error.Here i am not understanding how to query Opportunity in account Trigger?

Comment: The standard system logic prevents deleting accounts with open opportunities by default, so this might not even be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need a query to do what you want here. Create a `Roll-up Summary Field` to count the child `Opportunity` records and use a `Validation Rule`.

**Roll-up Summary Field**

1. Navigate to the `Account` setup page.
2. Under `Account Custom Fields & Relationships`, click the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
3. Select `Roll-Up Summary` as the `Data Type` for your new field.
4. Name your field, preferably something like `Opportunity Count`.
5. Select `Opportunities` as your `Summarized Object`.
6. Select `COUNT` as your `Rollup Type`.
7. Save your field.

**Validation Rule**

1. Create  a new `Validation Rule` for the `Account` object.
2. Use this formula:

   ```
   Opportunity_Count__c > 0
   ```

Comment: Ah but you can't fire Validation Rule on delete...still have to query for it.